# Very General Question: Ways to Delay Relay Activation

Tags: switches, relay, solid-state-relay, delay

This is a general question to round out my knowledge of relays.

Say, for example, I close a circuit that powers a NO relay. How would I go about delaying the activation of this relay for a specific amount of time, with an accuracy of 5 or 10ms?

Comment: Do you want to delay both edges? what about using a CMOS RC delay then buffer

Comment: Given the "general nature" of your question, I'd add that these days that would be a SOT-23-6 MCU with a tiny program in it plus any necessary associated external circuitry needed to drive the relay from the MCU. You could also use the initial signal's active-going edge to both reset an FF and also start a one-shot timer. The timer's later inactive-going edge toggles the FF which, with appropriate added circuitry, activates the relay. (Don't forget power-on issues for any solution.) Or all the RC stuff you see in answers below.

Answer (score 2):

In old days, it was made like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6KXQ2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1, R2, C1 are not real values, you have to find it. I have found this way of delaying relays in some old russian milling machine that I have retrofited it with PLC. Before dismantling it, I had to understand what those delays were used for, so I could implent them in PLC. It was long time ago, so I can't remember the values, but it was done in that way.

Answer (score 0):

In general you would delay application of the voltage to the coil. If the overall time is short, a simple RC circuit works well, though resetting it so you get the same time after a short off time is not necessarily trivial (you're talking 1% of a 0.5 second delay).

In the old days we would use a programmable UJT (a type of 4-layer thyristor) and an SCR. There were CMOS counter circuits developed for long time delays. In 2020 you might well choose to use a microcontroller with either an internal RC clock or an external crystal.

Details (where the devil is) include how quickly and how exactly you reset the circuit between operations. It's easier if the minimum interruption of power is relatively long. Analog circuits can have issues if a timing operation is under way and a very brief interruption takes place before it times out.

Answer (score 0):

I would also support RC circuit to slow down the relay activation. As a downside - turn off time will go up as well. Of course it all depends on how much space you have and how many components and pins you're ready to use for it. You can always have an additional N-ch mosfet near the relay coil that will connect it to ground. So you will have 2 control signals: main relay controls and mosfet controls.

First you keep MOSFET closed. When you need to turn the relay on, you use RC, so you'll have a pause. But when you turn it off, you pull down the RC controlling line but also open MOSFET at the same time, so the discharge has no resistance.

P.S. I didn't edit the default values in the picture, it was a made-in-30-seconds sketch
P.P.S. You may need to have one more resistor between the capacitor and the coil

[image]